# About the greek style

Tags: packages, greek

[image]

I like this type of style for greek letter (the red part in the picture), can anybody tell me how to realize in latex and which package is necessary, Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: My welcome. Where have you taken, this picture, is it possible, please? Have you a pdf?

Comment: Did you try `\varepsilon`?

Answer (score 1):

Two solution for the similar style of your image: using (1) `\usepackage{kpfonts}` or (2) `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}`.

**(1)**
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\[\bm{\dot{\sigma}}(\underline{z})=\mathbb{L}(\underline{z})\,\colon\,\bm{\dot{\varepsilon}}(\underline{z})\]
\end{document}
```

or **(2)**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\[\bm{\dot{\sigma}}(\underline{z})=\mathbb{L}(\underline{z})\,\colon\,\bm{\dot{\varepsilon}}(\underline{z})\]
\end{document}
```